# Pasting multiple lines into a TEdit

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi

With respect to a TEdit component, would it be possible for the component to handle a multi-line paste from the Windows Clipboard by converting line breaks to spaces?

In other words, if the following data was on the Windows Clipboard:

```
Hello
world
!
```

...and the user placed their cursor in a TEdit then pressed CTRL+V, would it be possible to have the TEdit display the input as:

Hello world !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd need to subclass the `TEdit` using an interposer class, and add a handler for the `WM_PASTE` message:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, adsdata, adsfunc, adstable;

type
  TEdit= class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
    procedure WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    AdsTable1: TAdsTable;
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

{ TEdit }

procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
var
  TempTxt: string;
begin
  TempTxt := Clipboard.AsText;
  TempTxt := StringReplace(TempTxt, #13#10, #32, [rfReplaceAll]);
  Text := TempTxt;
end;

end.
```

Comment: And if you have one specific case and you feel subclassing is overkill, you can assign a new message handler to `YourEdit.WindowProc`.